# How to check if the input string contains both numericals as well as alphabets?, *Only using "if" or "while" as main functions with other

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
P = input("Your password: ")

if P.isalnum() and not P.isalpha() and not P.isdigit:

        print ("Valid password.")
else:

        print("Password must contain both numbers and alphabets.")
```

If the password is "abcd" , the command should yell at the user , the "else" statement. Same goes if the input contains "1234".

The above code was not working for me. Whenever I typed "abcd12", it yelled that the password must contain both numbers and alphabets.

Comment: For 1st line think you meant: `P = input("Your password: ")`

Comment: Oh .... I'm really sorry for that..I apologise.

Comment: "isdigit" is a method as well, you're missing the calling parentheses - `P.isdigit()`

Answer (score 3):

```
P = input("Your password: ")

if P.isalnum() and not (P.isdigit() or P.isalpha()):
      print ("Valid password.")
else:

    print("Password must contain both numbers and alphabets.")
```

Comment: Thank you so much..was simple but..it wasn't in my mind.